# How can I stop content from columns overlapping other columns in a gridpane in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I have an animation inside a gridpane and the animation overlaps the other columns in the gridpane.

I have tried to stop this by introducing:

```
popUpWin.setHgrow(msg, Priority.NEVER);
```

I have tried adding padding to the gridpane:

```
popUpWin.setHgap(8);
popUpWin.setVgap(6);
popUpWin.setPadding(new Insets(10, 20, 12, 20));
```

My Code so far:

```
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class VRAnimate extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    GridPane popUpWin = new GridPane();

    Image imageComp = new Image("Loading VR-computer.png");
    ImageView imageViewComp = new ImageView();
    imageViewComp.setImage(imageComp);
    imageViewComp.setFitWidth(200);
    imageViewComp.setFitHeight(150);

    Image imageVR = new Image("Loading VR-VR.png");
    ImageView imageViewVR = new ImageView();
    imageViewVR.setImage(imageVR);
    imageViewVR.setFitWidth(241);
    imageViewVR.setFitHeight(215);

    Text msg = new Text("01001001 00100000 01101100 01101111 01110110 01100101 00100000"
            + "01001001 01101110 01110100 01100101 01110010 01100110 01100001 01100011 01100101"
            + "00100000 01000100 01100101 01110011 01101001 01100111 01101110 00101100 00100000"
            + "01001001 01101110 01110100 01100101 01110010 01100001 01100011 01110100 01101001"
            + "01101111 01101110 00100000 01100001 01101110 01100100 00100000 01000101 01111000"
            + "01110000 01100101 01110010 01101001 01100101 01101110 01100011 01100101");
    msg.setTextOrigin(VPos.TOP);
    msg.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.NORMAL,40));
    msg.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    double msgWidth = 600;
    KeyValue initKeyValue = new KeyValue(msg.translateXProperty(), -1000);//new KeyValue(msg.translateXProperty(), 600);
    KeyFrame initFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, initKeyValue);
    KeyValue endKeyValue = new KeyValue(msg.translateXProperty(), 600);//new KeyValue(msg.translateXProperty(), -1.0 * msgWidth);
    KeyFrame endFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10), endKeyValue);
    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(initFrame, endFrame);
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();

    popUpWin.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(300));
    popUpWin.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(700));
    popUpWin.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(300));

    popUpWin.addColumn(0,imageViewComp);
    popUpWin.addColumn(1,msg);
    popUpWin.addColumn(2,imageViewVR);

    GridPane.setHalignment(imageViewComp, HPos.CENTER);
    GridPane.setHalignment(imageViewVR, HPos.CENTER);

    FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(2500), imageViewVR);
    ft.setFromValue(1.0);
    ft.setToValue(0.2);
    ft.setAutoReverse(true);
    ft.setCycleCount(50);
    ft.play();

    Scene scene = new Scene(popUpWin, 1300, 215, Color.rgb(234,136,55));
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

I am expecting the Text Msg which is column 1 in the gridpane to not overlap the text onto the other columns

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I am using a gridpane that has 3 columns. The center column overlaps the outer columns.
 https://xwoxoa.bl.files.1drv.com/y4mDPj_gKcHGfnMLf07WTKbiZU6NllSf4r0718eficIKjlk7zbr9tIctIgmqnCIjHdM3uCAfTpeBTtlrTrq_UDpGAyrUg8wARGs8ziqeBOd7LprB2IIlgZo40Ny4ab_MKI7d2tiZKS5oaPWkvfO4NQt2h6K7u0ic2wwcJ_xpKxiQnre_Fo3k7g5qxPDPiExKhYKE-V2Ut3Ee5EfGNiYBQx7FQ?width=1314&height=262&cropmode=none

Comment: I have also provided the rest of the code